# How to toggle input value?

Tags: jquery, input, toggle

How to update this jQuery code, that each link may add\delete just its text to the input?

```
$("a").click(function (e) { 
e.preventDefault();
var elem = $("input[name$='what']");
var text = $(this).text();
if (elem.val()) {
    elem.val("");
} else {
    elem.val( elem.val() + " " + text );
}
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fxdcoejm/5/)

```
  <form>
  <p>name*</p>
  <input class="name" type="text" name="name">
  <p>phone*</p>
  <input class="phone" type="text" name="phone">
  <p>services</p>
  <input class="what" type="text" name="what">
  <input class="send" type="submit" name="send" value="send">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of which services are selected. There are any number of ways to do that. Here are two:

#### Using a class on the `a` element

Add a `service` class to each of the `a` elements, and then:

```
$("a").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $("input[name$='what']");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    elem.val(
        $("a.service.selected").map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get().join(" ")
    );
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxdcoejm/6/)

Note that this approach will always have the services in the text box in the order in which the `a` elements appear in the document (not the order in which the user clicked them). Which may or may not be what you want.

#### Using an array

```
var selectedServices = [];
$("a").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $("input[name$='what']");
    var service = $(this).text();
    var index = $.inArray(service, selectedServices);
    if (index === -1) {
        // Not in the array: add it
        selectedServices.push(service);
    } else {
        // In the array: remove it
        selectedServices.splice(index, 1);
    }
    elem.val(selectedServices.join(" "));
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxdcoejm/7/)

Note that this approach will always have the services in the text box in the order in which the user clicked them.

Comment: Thank you! I choose the first way!

Answer (score -1):

A working JSFIDDLE: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fixit/fxdcoejm/1/)

Always set the value to "" - before each click.

```
$("a").click(function (e) { 
e.preventDefault();
var elem = $("input[name$='what']");
var text = $(this).text();
    elem.val(""); // set value to ""
    elem.val( elem.val() + " " + text );
});
```